# Storage is not getting returned by taquito

Tags: taquito

I am retrieving the instance of my contract properly with taquito as shown in the taquito example:

const tezos = new TezosToolkit('https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io/');
Then I go with tezos.at...
And get back the instance.

When I then proceed with instance.storage() I get back that true property of undefined cannot be read.

Anybody got a clue why this is happening?

Comment: Can you provide information to reproduce, what is the contract address, and what version of Taquito are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that you really need the latest taquito version since the do upgrade. All previous versions don't seem to work anymore.

Problem is fixed by upgrading.